# How do we use SwipeableRow (or SwipeableListView) introduced in React Native's v0.27.0?

Tags: facebook, react-native, react-native-listview

I have been developing mobile application using React Native, for Android and iOS platforms. I was looking for Swipeable ListView and came across [SwipeableRow](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/tree/master/Libraries/Experimental/SwipeableRow) in React Native's [Release v0.27.0](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/releases/tag/v0.27.0). There seems to be no documentation yet. If anyone has used it, please guide us on

- What exactly it does?
- How to use it?

Answer (score 4):

There is no documentation yet as it is considered an experimental feature at this point. There is a Pull Request you could reference until such time that documentation is available.

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/8782

Comment: Still the same case after 8 years